# How to pass prop to custom root component in material-ui@next when using TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui

I want to render a `ListItem` component with react-router `Link` as a root component as follows:

```
        <ListItem
          to="/profile"
          component={Link}
        >
          Profile
        </ListItem>
```

However, I get a TypeScript error:

```
(50,15): error TS2339: Property 'to' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ListItemProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

Obviously, the `to` prop used by the `Link` component is part of the `ListItem` props interface...

How to work around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't reject extra props that are passed with the prop-spread syntax, so this works:

```
    <ListItem {...{to: "/profile"}} component={Link}>
      Profile
    </ListItem>
```